# Template’s CSS is not styling the HTML

Tags: html, css

I've downloaded a [template from w3layouts.com](http://w3layouts.com/minima-freebiesxpress-mobile-website-template) to make a website, and when I unzip the layout and try to open any of the HTML files, none of the CSS styling the page (it just looks as if there's no CSS).

When I inspect the HTML files, the CSS appears to be included in the header. For example, this is included in smartphone/blog.html's header:

```
<link href="smartphone/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Comment: Did you just open the file, or did you actually put the files on server? Also it looks the files require PHP (to serve the files, and for client feature detection), they dont seem to be static html.

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply **`update this link tag`**

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Because in this template **`href="smartphone/css/style.css"`**. but actually **css dictonary** present in **same level** where other html file are. So you just **update html file** link tag to **`new href="css/style.css".`**

---

Is this template is for **website, phone** so you must set this template using **`index.php`** file to set dynamic path. but above solution is **static not a dynamic**. if you have to set dynamic path you must **configure template step**.